# Hashes in hashes ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm passing the below information through parameter from view to controller

```
parameters:{"Something"=>{"a" => "1", "b" => "0", "c" => "1", "d" => "0" #and so on}}
```

I want to access all the characters that have "1" as their value and concatenate into the string.

I tried

```
Something.each do |key, value|
if(value == "1")
string = string + key
end 
end
```

It is throwing error saying that it could not execute nil.each and that i might be expecting an array. 
It appears to me that Something is a hash and in turn has some hashes in it. 
So i initialised Something to

```
Something = Hash.new { |Something, k| Something[k] = Hash.new }
```

But i still get the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just work with the `params` hash. This should do what you need:

```
params["Something"].select {|k, v| v == "1"}.keys.reduce(:+)
```

- `select` filters the params to only those with the value `"1"`
- `keys` returns an array with all the keys in the hash
- `reduce` joins all elements with a concat operation (+)

**Edit**

To concatenate and add the "Extra" word:

- For each parameter:

  ```
  params["Something"].select {|k, v| v == "1"}.keys.inject("") {|result, p| result += "Extra #{p}"}
  ```
- Only to the extra parameters, but not to the first one:

  ```
  params["Something"].select {|k, v| v == "1"}.keys.inject {|result, p| result += "Extra #{p}"}
  ```

See more information on `inject` [here](http://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/inject).

Comment: @alfonso
Thank you, i found that i needed only the array of keys and i need some extra information to be concatenated along with the key, like "a + "extra"". So i did not use keys.reduce(:+). Is there anyway i can write something like this - keys.reduce(: "Extra"+) so that the extra string gets added to every key?

Comment: Thank you, that worked. I will study more about inject and reduce from the link you provided.